latex error: loading a class or package
I a get some serious issue with this error
I need some help with this code
here is the preamble
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{calligra,frcursive}

\usepackage[greek,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multimedia}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Uppsala}
\useoutertheme[hideothersubsections]{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
\usecolortheme{sidebartab}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!100!blue}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\usefonttheme[]{serif}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{fg=blue}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}{Table of contents}
  \small \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
}


\def\ds{\displaystyle}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sig}{sigm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cd}{CD}


\title[Capacitated Vehicle  Routing Problem]{An Attractors-based Particle Swarm Optimization for multiobjective Capacitated Vehicle  Routing Problem}
\author[S. C. Rawhoudine]{\textcolor{cyan}{\underline{Rawhoudine Said Charriffaini} and Abdoul-hafar Halassi Bacar}}
\institute[AIU]{\textcolor{cyan}{ATLANTIC INTERNATIONAL UNIVERSITY,\\ HONOLULU, HAWAII}}
\date[\today]{}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.cm]{logo_AIU.jpg}}



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Table of contents}
 \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
...................
...................
\end{document}


The example can be simplified to \documentclass{beamer} \usepackage{arabtex} \begin{document} \end{document}

@Chamanga Unrelated, but a lot of the packages you load aren't necessary for a beamer presentation.

Instead of using arabtex the usage of a UTF8 native TeX engine (LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX) and an Arabic OTF font is recommended. See the babel manual for information about writing Arabic with babel using \babelfont.
